# list product table and product image table --- join query

Tags: mysql

list product table and product image table --- join query

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `p_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_names` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `p_price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `p_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productimage` (
  `pimage_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `p_id` int(10) NOT NULL,----------------------------foreign Key 
  PRIMARY KEY (`pimage_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: Are you just expecting readymade Query or you tried something ?

Comment: tried but not getting

Comment: You havenot set **Foreign key** , you just made -----Foreign key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query would look something like this.

```
Select p.p_id, p_price, p_description, if(isnull(img), 'no', 'yes') as image_uploaded
From product p
Left Join productimage pm
On p.p_id = pm.p_id
```

The query will join the two tables together on p_id and display yes or no if the image had been uploaded.

Comment: `image uploaded` should be One Word. Use underscore between it

Comment: PO specified name of column in image.

Comment: No duplicate field in other table so no overlap would be present.